# SugarCRM Calendar In Opportunity DetailView

Tags: php, calendar, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to display a Calendar under the DetailView for a particular Opportunity record. I'd like it to look similar to the below image:

[image: Calendar under the DetailView]

Comment: Hi Towerofnix
Nothing....
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps try something, then? :)